# Getting webcam to work in Raspberry Pi

Tags: debian, usb, camera, raspberry-pi

I am trying to get a HAMA webcam to work with my raspberry pi with the raspbian os.

When I type usb-devices I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ usb-devices

T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 1
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.01
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.1.9+ dwc_otg_hcd
S:  Product=DWC OTG Controller
S:  SerialNumber=bcm2708_usb
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 3
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=02 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0424 ProdID=9512 Rev=02.00
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=2mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 1 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=02 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0424 ProdID=ec00 Rev=02.00
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=2mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=ff Driver=smsc95xx

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=02 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0c45 ProdID=6142 Rev=01.01
S:  Product=USB camera
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
```

I guess that last one is the camera. What are my next steps to get it to take some pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you (it's about streaming video from connected camera):
http://sirlagz.net/2012/08/04/how-to-stream-a-webcam-from-the-raspberry-pi/